# How to simplify the result of (eval (f x y))?

Tags: z3

How can I simplify the Boolean expression obtained as a result of evaluating an uninterpreted function? 
For instance, in the example: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/G8sL,

```
(eval (f x y))
```

yields (not (and (not x) (not y)))

I want to instead get the expression (or x y).

```
(simplify (eval (f x y))
```

gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in the SMT-LIB 2.0 front-end.
You should consider one the programmatic front-ends for Z3.
For example, here is how to do it using the Z3 Python front-end (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/HplYj)):

```py
B = BoolSort()
f = Function('f', B, B, B)
x, y = Bools('x y')
b1, b2 = Bools('b1 b2')

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([b1, b2], Implies(Or(b1, b2), f(b1, b2))))
s.add(Exists([b1, b2], Not(f(b1, b2))))

print(s.check())
m = s.model()
print(m.evaluate(f(x, y)))
print(simplify(m.evaluate(f(x, y)), elim_and=True))
```